# vue.js / Vue getter not defined error

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I get an error with my App.vue component , getter: **logged**

```
<li id="shoppinglists" v-if="!logged">...

ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Property or method "logged" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. 
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

I don't understand why it's stated as non-defined, as I don't get error with another defined getter: **currentUserId**

```
<li v-else id="shoppinglists"><router-link :to="{ name: 'ShoppingLists', params: { id: currentUserId } }" >Shopping Lists</router-link></li>
```

Bothe are defined as computed props :

```
<script>
import store from '@/vuex/store'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      { currentUserId: 'getCurrentUserId' },
      { logged: 'getCurrentUserStatus' }
    ])
  },
  store
}
</script>
```

and my vex/getters.js is :

**vuex/getters.js**

```
export default {
  getCurrentUserStatus: state => state.logged,
  getCurrentUserId: state => state.currentUserId,
  ...
}
```

and my store is

**vuex/store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import getters from './getters'
...

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
  logged: false,
  currentUserId: '',
  ...
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an object to `...mapGetters` if you want to use the getters with different name

So the syntax is:

```
...mapGetters({
      currentUserId: 'getCurrentUserId',
      logged: 'getCurrentUserStatus' 
 })
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. I did not get it right in writing it... I thought it was an array of objects... now I an see the vex binding in my Vue tool... !